# (Java/Spring) Accessing class elements using entityType.getJavaType()

Tags: java, spring-boot, instanceof, entities

I created a generic Spring Entiy-Class "TableWithId" which is intended to be inherited by other classes.

Here a snipped from the base class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "__base_table")
public class TableWithId {
    public static String EntityLabel = "All data";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;
```

So in my subclasses I am implementing further fields etc. This works very well, It creates, fills and lists content as expected ...

Now I want to be able to get a list of all my entities. This works fine with, well at least to get the names and class-names.

```
entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()
```

Based on the entity name I can also load entities based on user parameters:

```
entityManager.createQuery("Select t from " + entityName + " t").getResultList();
```

Now there are two things I cannot do:

(1) Access static java properties of my classes, I actually want to access "public static String EntityLabel" at runtime using the java-class returned by "entityType.getJavaType()". In fact I'd like to do something like this:

```
((TableWithId)  entityType.getJavaType()).EntityLabel
```

(2) For security reasons I also like protecting the system by not allowing the user to make queries on other entities which do not inherit from TableWithId. I'd like to do something like:

```
entityType.getJavaType() instanceof TableWithId
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

getJavaType gives you a class instance. you could access a static  field via reflection:
`entityType.getJavaType().getField("EntityLabel").get(null)`

if you want to test if a class is the same as another of its superclass or superinterface you should use isAssignableFrom:

`Class.forName("xxxx.TableWithId").isAssignableFrom(entityType.getJavaType())`

Comment: Thanks a lot I figured out, even so I do not now how to do the instanceof as I do not have an object at this point... I'll post my implementation below.

Comment: the proposed solution regarding isAssignableFrom works without object ...provided you know the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to pero_hero I figured it out, except classpath...

Here my complete solution ...

```
public class EntityInfo {
    public Class myclass;
    public String label;
    public Hashtable<String, Action> actions;
    public String name;

    public EntityInfo(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        try {
            this.myclass =  Class.forName(name);
            this.label = (String) this.myclass.getField("EntityLabel").get(null);
            this.actions = (Hashtable<String, Action>) this.myclass.getMethod("getActions").invoke(null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```